# ActionBar icon change latency

Tags: android, toolbar, swipe, latency

I am developing android app with `ActionBar` layout like below

[image]

When swiping action occurs the `Fragment` changes accordingly. Hence the color of the `Toolbar` icons. The color change occurs if the `Fragment` is visible and I implemented it like this

```
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (visible) {
            MainActivity.tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(MainActivity.icons[4+2]); //purple icons are +4th index of the "icons" array
        }else{
            MainActivity.tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(MainActivity.icons[2]);
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but irritating thing is that the color change is too slow for the human perception. The page swipes than after couple of milliseconds the icon changes to purple which is very late.

I know because of the swiping action must be completed to notify `Fragment` visibility, but how can I achieve instant icon change, any idea or information is appreciated.

Note: Tapping directly on the icon changes to the purple one immediately.

Comment: When is your `setMenuVisibility` getting called ?

Comment: When the fragment is opened and closed